# Как привязать команду к заголовку подменю tkinter menu

Tags: python, tkinter, меню

Есть меню с вложенными подменю. Я знаю как привязать функцию к пунктам меню, но не знаю, возможно ли привязать команду к заголовку вложенного меню?

**Если возможно, то как?** Пример приводить не буду, слишком большой получится, думаю вопрос понятен.

Если такой возможности нет, то какой альтернативой заменить меню, чтобы был похожий функционал?

Comment: Что такое "заголовок вложенного меню"?

Comment: Элемент, при наведении или нажатии на который открывается подменю.

Comment: Никак, cascade не поддерживает реакцию на нажатие. Если обязательно меню нужно, а нужно отображение иерархии, посмотрите TreeView. Там на любой элемент дерева можно добавить реакцию.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал существовании такого виджета. Обязательно попробую